# Remove Summation on Power BI SQL Server Column

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, business-intelligence, data-analysis

How do I remove a summation property for a Power BI SQL table? I have a Customer Transaction Table. For some reason PowerBI is trying to Measure Sum the CustomerTransactionId primary key row. I do not want this added. Please see picture below.
I just want to display all rows in a table.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTransaction] 
(
    [Customertransactionid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    [Customerid] [int] NULL,
    [Quantitybought] [int] NULL,
)
```

[msdn](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Remove-Summation-on-Power-BI-SQL-Server-Column/m-p/506236#M236388)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually done in PowerBI under the modeling ribbon/tab.

When you click on a field (on the right where they are all listed under Fields is fine), the modeling ribbon changes to reflect all settings for that particular field.

Under **Default Summarization** select '*Do not summarize*'.

PowerBI sets Default Summarizations regardless of the data source.